# SQLiteDatabase.query() возвращает пустой Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

При запросе к БД на Android, испльзуя selection в методе `query()`, возвращается пустой `Cursor`.
Собственно, сам запрос:

```
var code = edit_code.text.toString().toUpperCase()
val db = DBHelper(activity).readableDatabase
val cursor = db.query(TABLE_AIRPORTS, arrayOf(AIRPORTS_ICAO, AIRPORTS_IATA), "$AIRPORTS_ICAO = ? OR $AIRPORTS_IATA = ?", arrayOf(code, code), null, null, null, "1")
```

Код DBHelper:

```
val DB_NAME = "mfp.db"
val DB_VERSION = 11

val logTag = "DBHelper"

val TABLE_AIRPORTS = "AIRPORTS"
val AIRPORTS_ID = "_ID"
val AIRPORTS_NAME = "NAME"
val AIRPORTS_CITY = "CITY"
val AIRPORTS_COUNTRY = "COUNTRY"
val AIRPORTS_IATA = "IATA"
val AIRPORTS_ICAO = "ICAO"
val AIRPORTS_LAT = "LAT"
val AIRPORTS_LNG = "LNG"
val AIRPORTS_ALT = "ALT"


class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Creating tables")
        createTables(db!!)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Upgrading tables")
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_AIRPORTS")
        createTables(db)
    }


    private fun createTables(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_AIRPORTS ($AIRPORTS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $AIRPORTS_NAME TEXT, $AIRPORTS_CITY TEXT," +
                "$AIRPORTS_COUNTRY TEXT, $AIRPORTS_ICAO TEXT, $AIRPORTS_IATA TEXT, $AIRPORTS_LAT NUMERIC, $AIRPORTS_LNG NUMERIC, $AIRPORTS_ALT NUMERIC)")
    }
}
```

Запрашиваемые данные в таблице, естественно, присутсвуют.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вы уверены, что опреатор $ работает в теле запроса именно так, как вы думаете (подставляет значение переменных). Есть предположение, что магия Kotlin не проникла так далеко.

Comment: Да. Вот такой запрос, например, работает нормально: `val cursor = db.query(TABLE_AIRPORTS, arrayOf(AIRPORTS_ID, AIRPORTS_ICAO, AIRPORTS_IATA), "$AIRPORTS_ID = ?", arrayOf("10000"), null, null, null)`. Т. е. эта проблема только с типом данных **TEXT**.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в самих данных. Все **stringи** по непонятным причинам записывались в таблицу заключенные в кавычки. Пять дней мне понадобилось, чтобы заметить эти кавычки, на которые до этого не обращал внимания. 🤦🤦🤦

> Человеческий мозг уникален. Он работает в режиме 24/7 с самого момента нашего рождения, каждый день. И останавливается только тогда, когда ты пишешь код.